# Should I check collections when overriding equals in entities?

Tags: java, jpa, equals, equality

I am wondering if I should check for equality of relations in entities or not. Suppose I have below entities:

```
@Entity
class A {
   // ...

   @OneToMany
   private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       //...
       A other = (A) obj;
       if(!bs.equals(other.getBs())) return false;
       // ...
    }
}

@Entity
class B {
   // ...
}
```

Should I check for the equality of the `bs` fields? It looks somehow strange, since `bs` may contain thousands of entities.

Comment: The class A probably has a unique identifier, isn't it enough to check that ID in your equals method? Also, ALWAYS override hashcode when overriding equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you check the equality of all the member entities is a question of your definition of equality.  Note that you cannot correctly override `equals()` at all without overriding `hashCode()` as well to ensure that equal objects have equal hash codes.

With that said, opinions vary on whether it is a good idea to override these methods for JPA entity classes at all.  If you do override them, then equality should probably be based only on a "business id" -- the property or properties of the entity that define its identity for business purposes, as distinct from its autogenerated PK.  This makes equality answer the question "do objects E1 and E2 represent the same persistent entity" in a way that works whether the entity objects' PKs have been read / assigned or not.  Following that principle would mean that you *do not* include the elements of associated collections in your determination.

If you have some other idea of equality that you want to be able to evaluate, then consider providing a different method for evaluating it, or even a different class responsible for performing such comparisons.  Possibly making your entity class `Comparable` could serve this purpose.

Comment: Ok, checking the identity keys makes sense, so this way a detached entity with different state but equal identity key with the original persisted entity is equal, right?

Comment: Pretty much yes, but be careful: you probably want to account not only for detached entities, but also for *new* ones.  That's the point of basing the evaluation on business identity rather than on a surrogate key.